# Redirecting in C++

Tags: c++, redirect, stdout, cout, io-redirection

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void foo(){
  streambuf *psbuf;
  ofstream filestr;
  filestr.open ("test.txt");
  psbuf = filestr.rdbuf(); 
  cout.rdbuf(psbuf);    
}

int main () {
  foo();
  cout << "This is written to the file";
  return 0;
}
```

Does cout write to the given file?

If not, is there a way to do it without sending the variables to foo, like `new`?

---

*update* :

I can't use a solution that uses class or uses global so plz can some
give me solution that use new. Also passing the from main to foo

```
streambuf *psbuf;
ofstream filestr;
```

should work right?

I am trying to do this but its not working?
I pass the stream to foo so it exist in the main so it wont end when foo finish.

```
 void foo(streambuf *psbuf){

  ofstream filestr;
  filestr.open ("test.txt");
  psbuf = filestr.rdbuf(); 
  cout.rdbuf(psbuf);    
}

int main () {
streambuf *psbuf
  foo(psbuf);
  cout << "This is written to the file";
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that by now compiled and run your code and found that you get a segmentation fault.

You are getting this because you create and open an `ofstream` object within `foo()`, which is then destroyed (and closed) at the end of `foo`. When you attempt to write to the stream in `main()`, you attempt to access a buffer which no longer exists.

**One** workaround to this is to make your `filestr` object global. There are plenty of better ones!

**Edit:** Here is a better solution as suggested by @MSalters:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class scoped_cout_redirector
{
public:
    scoped_cout_redirector(const std::string& filename)
        :backup_(std::cout.rdbuf())
        ,filestr_(filename.c_str())
        ,sbuf_(filestr_.rdbuf())
    {
        std::cout.rdbuf(sbuf_);
    }

    ~scoped_cout_redirector()
    {
        std::cout.rdbuf(backup_);
    }

private:
    scoped_cout_redirector();
    scoped_cout_redirector(const scoped_cout_redirector& copy);
    scoped_cout_redirector& operator =(const scoped_cout_redirector& assign);

    std::streambuf* backup_;
    std::ofstream filestr_;
    std::streambuf* sbuf_;
};


int main()
{
    {
        scoped_cout_redirector file1("file1.txt");
        std::cout << "This is written to the first file." << std::endl;
    }


    std::cout << "This is written to stdout." << std::endl;

    {
        scoped_cout_redirector file2("file2.txt");
        std::cout << "This is written to the second file." << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "There are better ones". Indeed, but it would be hard to find them without a pointer. Here's one: read up on RAII. Most of the code from the function `foo` should really be moved to a constructor, and the matching destructor should do the cleanup (such as restoring cout to its old state).

Comment: Indeed. @mati seems to have deliberately omitted restoring `cout` to its former state when lifting the code out of http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/rdbuf/ into `foo()`. RAII seemed too far out of the scope of the question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your code should work but ... Why don't you try yourself ? You will see if everything is written in test.txt or not.

Comment: It seems to me that it doesn't, but your question is still valid :-)