# operator overloading

Tags: c++

How can I overload << operator (cout) so that it can be written to a file. Whenever << occurs it should be appended to the file i.e. instead of displaying on the screen it should be written to the file.

can i get a code for this...i am new to c++ and code written by me is not working..

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/fstream/open/

Comment: For smaller programs (tools) it is actually not a bad thing to just write to cout and direct to a file when running the program (mytool > output.txt)

Answer (score 3):

Normally you provide `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const YourClass&)` for your class and write to a file stream as follows:

```
std::ofstream ofs("out");
ofs << yourObject;
```

where `yourObject` is an object of `YourClass`.

Answer (score 3):

Your overloaded `<<` operator shouldn't care what kind of output stream that it goes to or whether it's appending or overwriting. It takes a `std::ostream&` and writes to it. If it's used with `cout`, then it's written to the console. If it's used with a `std::ofstream`, then it writes to a file. If that `std::ofstream` was opened to overwrite, then it overwrites. If it was opened to append, then it appends.

All that your overloaded `<<` operator should care about is that it's writing to an output stream. What that stream represents is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

This overloading is already done for the C++ file stream. The name **cout** means console out and the spirit is, it will output to console. 
One thing you could do is use freopen(), to redirect all output to a file.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to send text to a file rather than the console, then `std::ofstream` is your friend. Like `cout`, your instance of `ofstream` shares the behaviour of `ostream` which already has a suitable `<<` `operator` for strings and can be used exactly as `cout`. Here's an example:

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream fout("somefile.txt");

    fout << "Some text" << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compile and run and you'll find that you have a new file in the current working directory:

```
% cat somefile.txt 
Some text
```

---

If you need to stream an object that doesn't have `operator <<` overloaded for `std::ostream`, then you you will need to overload the operator, like this:

```
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const SomeClass& instance)
{
    instance.print(os);
    return os;
}
```

You'll need `void SomeClass::print(std::ostream& os)` defined to send its private data to `os` (this saves you making the `<<` a `friend` of your class).

---

Were you talking purely about `cout`, then this isn't "operator overloading", this is stream redirection. But, yes, it is possible (too) by setting the associated stream buffer using [`std::basic_ios::rdbuf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdbuf).

Here is [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3667321/78845) from "[Redirecting in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3667201/78845)":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class scoped_cout_redirector
{
public:
    scoped_cout_redirector(const std::string& filename)
        :backup_(std::cout.rdbuf())
        ,filestr_(filename.c_str())
        ,sbuf_(filestr_.rdbuf())
    {
        std::cout.rdbuf(sbuf_);
    }

    ~scoped_cout_redirector()
    {
        std::cout.rdbuf(backup_);
    }

private:
    scoped_cout_redirector();
    scoped_cout_redirector(const scoped_cout_redirector& copy);
    scoped_cout_redirector& operator =(const scoped_cout_redirector& assign);

    std::streambuf* backup_;
    std::ofstream filestr_;
    std::streambuf* sbuf_;
};


int main()
{
    {
        scoped_cout_redirector file1("file1.txt");
        std::cout << "This is written to the first file." << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "This is written to stdout." << std::endl;

    {
        scoped_cout_redirector file2("file2.txt");
        std::cout << "This is written to the second file." << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it is not cout it is overloading << operator

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have updated my answer accordingly.