# Modification libstdc++-v3 in file ios_init.cc

Tags: c++

I want to modify `ios_init.cc` so that `cout` output will not be shown on the screen. I do not have option to recompile the binary.

I am trying in `ios_base::Init::Init()`.

Does anyone have the knowledge as to what exactly I need to comment out.

Comment: Why not just redirect the output?

Answer (score 3):

You *don't want* to modify any Standard Library file!

You *want* to stop `std::cout` updating the console. You can do this by [redirecting `std::cout`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3667321/78845). The example to which I linked redirects to a file, but you can easily modify it to redirect to nowhere:

```
#include <iostream>

class scoped_cout_silencer
{
public:
    scoped_cout_silencer()
        :backup_(std::cout.rdbuf())
    {
        std::cout.rdbuf(NULL);
    }

    ~scoped_cout_silencer()
    {
        std::cout.rdbuf(backup_);
    }

private:
    scoped_cout_silencer(const scoped_cout_silencer& copy);
    scoped_cout_silencer& operator =(const scoped_cout_silencer& assign);

    std::streambuf* backup_;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Now you see me." << std::endl;
    {
        scoped_cout_silencer silence;
        std::cout << "Now you don't." << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Now you see me." << std::endl;
}
```

[See it run!](http://ideone.com/85Sgo)